# What does this link mean?

Tags: facebook, http, google-ads-api

I saw this:

```
http://memeburn.com/2012/02/anonymous-is-shutting-down-the-internet/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+memeburncom+%28memeburn%29
```

But I've seen it loads. The part I'm referring to is:

```
?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+memeburncom+%28memeburn%29
```

Is this some kind of tracking tool? And if so, what? I got this link off facebook, but I've seen it on Adwords too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `utm_` query string parameters are [to do with Google Analytics](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55578).

Comment: But it also appears on Facebook links?